# with jsRender, how do you pull a specific item from array using something other than ordinal position?

Tags: javascript, json, templates, jsrender

I'm trying to render some JSON data using jsRender.  Below is my sample JSON data

```
"PageContentList": [
    {
        "ContentId": 51, 
        "Title": "60 seconds with Rick", 
        "ContentMediaTypeList": [
            {
                "MimeType": "image/png", 
                "MediaTypeName": "Image", 
                "Path": "http://local.admin.solutiaconsulting.com/uploads/4a906d8e-983a-4b54-a627-0e8d48145620.png"
            }, 
            {
                "MimeType": "video/webm", 
                "MediaTypeName": "Video", 
                "Path": "http://local.admin.solutiaconsulting.com/uploads/3a6c56c3-0ef9-4f57-9c84-9caa48a09044.webm"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to pull the different images based on MediaTypeName instead of the ordinal position.  I know I can do this:

{{:ContentMediaTypeList[1].Path}}

and I know I can do this:

{{for ContentMediaTypeList}}
{{if MediaTypeName == 'Video'}}
{{:Path}}
{{/if}}
{{/for}}

But the second approach seems cumbersome and wasteful.  Is what I want to do even possible?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use helper functions to process your data (step through the list and return the one with the targeted media type), and then do 
`{{:~mediaType('Image').Path}}`.

You can even define a custom tag and do:
`{{mediaType 'Image'}}{{:Path}}{{/mediaType}}`.

Take a look at the [samples](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/index.html) and you'll find examples of those techniques.

Comment: That's a good answer because that's exactly what he asked for in the first place. But I do think that the solution that Tom figured out by himself is even better. Using these helper functions would put more logic into the view and also make it more abstract since the real logic is hidden in a helper. Turning it into two different arrays is really straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it, because you are not supposed to perform that kind of logic in the view. Place your filter in the model or a controller before you render it.

The one exception I can think of in this case is if you would like to limit the number of items to display. That might or might not be a suitable task for the view depending on the situation.

**Examples:**

**Keep the logic of a limit out of the view:**
-  List of Question on Stack Overflow with paging (limit, offset, sorting)

**Enforce a limit in the view:**
- A list of attached images for each question. Your mobile view only have room to show one per question. The view suitable for desktop have room for three.

How to structure your application and where to place your logic is a debate with many opinions though. This style of separation is what I've been taught from experience and peers, but I am sure that there are many out there with different idéas.

Here's a simple way to filter your data using underscore.js.

```
 var videoContent = _.filter(contentMediaTypeList, function(mediaType) {
      return mediaType.mediaTypeName == "video"; 
 });
```

Working `JSFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/n98yW/

Or create a `closure` out of it for reusability

```
var mediaTypeFilter = function(mediaTypeName) {
     return function(contentMediaTypeList) {
           return _.filter(contentMediaTypeList, function(currMediaType) {
                return currMediaType.MediaTypeName == mediaTypeName;
           });
     }
};
```

And use it like this

```
var videoFilter = mediaTypeFilter("video");    
var videoContent = videoFilter(contentMediaTypeList);
```

Here's another `JSFiddle` for this solution using a closure: http://jsfiddle.net/GA55g/2/

Comment: thank you for your input.  I think the view should be able to pull things out of the data provided to it in order to generate the desired output.  I'm not applying any business rules to the data at the view.  I'm just trying to pluck data from the data sent to the view.  Is this not appropriate?

Comment: It depends your view of application layers and how they are supposed to communicate. If you really want to use the template language in JSRender for this, then I think that the for-loop you used in your question is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Charlie for your reply.  I ended up changing the structure of my JSON to this:

```
"PageContentList": [
    {
        "ContentId": 44, 
        "Title": "Company Name", 
        "Gallery": {
            "Images": [
                {
                    "Path": "http://local.admin.solutiaconsulting.com/uploads/9b577ef7-ea8a-42a1-b967-89debbc634c0.jpg", 
                    "MimeType": "image/jpeg", 
                    "ImageWidth": 0, 
                    "ImageHeight": 0, 
                    "AltText": null
                }
            ], 
            "Videos": [ ]
        }
    },
   .... 
]
```

Then for my template:

```
{{for PageContentList}}
<video id="whatIsSolutiaVideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="{{:Gallery.Images[0].ImageWidth}}" height="{{:Gallery.Images[0].ImageHeight}}" poster={{:Gallery.Images[0].Path}}" preload="auto">
{{for Gallery.Videos}}
<source type="{{:MimeType}}" src="{{:Path}}">
 {{/for}}
 </video>
 {{/for}}
```

I know each JSON data will have a section for Images, Videos, etc.  Now it becomes a data entry issue.  If the data entry person did their job right, then there will be data.  The approach I moved to ensures the correct data structure.  Thanks for forcing me to think through this.

Comment: +1 Splitting videos and images into two different arrays makes your code less complex and that's always a good thing. A great solution.